# Scripted Copy of all Materials/Material slots from another Object

Tags: python, scripting

How can i copy all Material settings from one object to another using Python ?

In the materials settings drop down menu in the user interface i can copy/paste materials:

```
Copy Material ( which calls bpy.ops.material.copy() )
Paste Material ( which calls bpy.ops.material.paste() )
```

When i try to call bpy.ops.material.copy() from the python console i get a {'CANCELLED'} and the subsequent bpy.ops.material.paste() does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Copy only the active Material:

```
tgt.active_material = src.active_material
```

Clean copy of all Material Slots from src to tgt:

```
tgt.data.materials.clear() # ensure the target material slots are clean
for mat in src.data.materials:
    tgt.data.materials.append(mat)
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to copy all properties of a material from another, apart from the texture in the texture slot ? I am trying to regroup textures of different materials into one materials'textures slots. I would like to copy all the materials properties, and then set the texture slots .The only way I can think of now is to copy in Python each property one by one, is that correct ?